# Run matlab in debug mode without gui but with figure support

Tags: matlab

If I run `matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -nodisplay` it seems to do the trick, but it won't show figures and other graphics.

Using `matlab -nodesktop -nosplash` shows figures but also shows the UI on breakpoints.

Is it possible to run matlab in a terminal and debug a script that uses figures without matlab opening the GUI when it hits a breakpoint?

Comment: You should give a bit more context. Why don't you want to use the UI for debugging, which would be the normal way of working? There may be another way around your issue.

Comment: Hi Brice, the idea is I want to replace the debug UI with VSCode's own debug UI. I already developed a plugin extension for octave. This extension interfaces with octave using stdin/out. I'm currently investigating the possibility of extending support to matlab. But matlab's UI pops up it takes control, and it also doesn't make sense to have both UIs displaying at the same time. That's why I need to avoid the debug UI without removing support for images. In octave this means running octave-cli, instead or octave. But there doesn't seem to be an equivalent binary in matlab.